# Kivy: pass data to another class popup

Tags: python, python-3.x, popup, kivy

I`m trying to make a simple GUI with Kivy(1.10) python 3.4.4 using a popup to show information of another class. But I have problems when I use funtion **init** to pass variable from one class (principal) to the class constructed with popup(Seleccionador)

Crash whe I use the funtion (abre_seleccionador)

Main.py

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.10.0')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.config import Config

Config.set('graphics','width', 800)
Config.set('graphics','height',500)

class CustomPopup(Popup):
    pass

class Seleccionador(Popup):

    def __init__(self,idea):
        super().__init__()
        self.idea_texto =idea

class Principal(BoxLayout):
    def abre_popup(self):

        the_popup =CustomPopup()
        the_popup.open()

    def abre_seleccionador(self):
        idea ='idea brillante'
        popin= Seleccionador(idea)
        popin.open()

class KvpopApp(App):
    title = 'Pruebas de pop up y filechooser'
    def build(self):
        return Principal()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    KvpopApp().run()
```

kv file:

```
<Principal>:
    orientation:'vertical'
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: 1,1,1,
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    Button:
        text: 'Abrir popup'
        on_press: root.abre_popup()
    Button:
        text: 'Abre seleccionador'
        on_press: root.abre_seleccionador()

<CustomPopup>:
    size_hint: 0.5,0.5
    auto_dismiss: False
    title: "Este es mi Popup"
    Button:
        text: 'Cerrar popup'
        on_press: root.dismiss()

<Seleccionador>:
    size_hint: 0.5,0.5
    auto_dismiss: False
    title: "Este es mi Popup"
    id: select
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            text: 'Cerrar'
            on_press: root.dismiss()
        Label:
            id: idea
            text: select.idea_texto
```

Answer (score 0):

Kv language rule is evaluated before class is initialized (before the `__init__` method is executed), therefore the instance attribute does not exist at that moment. The simplest thing is that you use a `StringProperty`:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.properties import StringProperty


Config.set('graphics', 'width', 800)
Config.set('graphics', 'height',500)


class CustomPopup(Popup):
    pass


class Seleccionador(Popup):
    idea_texto = StringProperty()    # <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

    def __init__(self, idea, **kwargs):
        super(Seleccionador, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.idea_texto = idea

class Principal(BoxLayout):
    def abre_popup(self):
        the_popup = CustomPopup()
        the_popup.open()

    def abre_seleccionador(self):
        idea = 'idea brillante'
        popin = Seleccionador(idea)
        popin.open()


class KvpopApp(App):
    title = 'Pruebas de pop up y filechooser'

    def build(self):
        return Principal()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    KvpopApp().run()
```